# How to read data out of a JSON array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to read data out of a JSON array and put them into variables. The only way worked for me was replacing the `}, {` with `}`, and the `[` and `]` with nothing and the reading it like it was a normal json file. How can i do that?
This is the Json File

```
    {
  "Area": "Hyper-V Cluster",
  "time_start": "2020-03-07T00:00:00",
  "time_end": "2020-03-07T23:59:59",
  "Systeme": [
    {
      "name": "test-s-hc001",
      "CPU [%]": 20.86,
      "Disk [%]": 4.32
    },
    {
      "name": "test-s-hc002",
      "CPU  [%]": 21.23,
      "Disk [%]": 49.42
    },
    {
      "name": "test-s-hc003",
      "CPU  [%]": 19.8,
      "Disk [%]": 7.47
    },
    {
      "name": "test-s-hc004",
      "CPU [%]": 20.01,
      "Disk [%]": 49.49
    },
    {
      "name": "test-s-hc005",
      "CPU [%]": 21.1,
      "Disk [%]": 48.41
    },
    {
      "name": "test-s-hc006",
      "CPU [%]": 21.01,
      "Disk [%]": 53.71
    },
    {
      "name": "test-s-hc007",
      "CPU [%]": 3.75,
      "Disk [%]": 62.72
    },
    {
      "name": "test-s-hc009",
      "CPU [%]": 4.11,
      "Disk [%]": 59.66
    }
  ]
}
```

My Code i actually tried but doesn not working looks like this:

```
import json

input_file = open ('test.json')
json_array = json.load(input_file)
windows_list = []

for item in json_array:
    windows_details = {"name":None, "Cpu [%]":None, "Disk [%]":None}
    windows_details['name'] = item['name']
    windows_details['CPU [%]'] = item['CPU [%]']
    windows_details['Disk[%]'] = item['Disk']
    windows_list.append(windows_details)

print(windows_list)
```

The output should look like this

```
test-s-hc001
20.86
4.32
test-s-hc002
```

...

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data you want is in 'Systeme' list, you can access each item by the following method:

```
for i in json_array['Systeme']:
    print(i['name'])
    print(i['CPU [%]'])
    print(i['Disk [%]'])
```

I think my answer echos what Miller have shared, but if you would like to get the output you shared, then this is the way to go. Besides, I don't really quite understand why would you append it back to a list, when `d['Systeme']` itself is almost identical to `windows_list`

Answer (score 4):

Your `json_array` is called `Systeme` in the json struct and not the top element.

So you should use that:

```
import json

input_file = open ('test.json')
json_array = json.load(input_file)
windows_list = []

for item in json_array['Systeme']:
    windows_details = {"name":None, "CPU [%]":None, "Disk [%]":None}
    windows_details['name'] = item['name']
    windows_details['CPU [%]'] = item['CPU [%]']
    windows_details['Disk [%]'] = item['Disk [%]']
    windows_list.append(windows_details)

print(windows_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
import json
with open("file.json", "r") as i:
    jsonObject = json.loads(i.read())
```

Then reference `jsonObject` as a dictionary like you normally would